# How to make a widget stick to the top while also having a scroll view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have made a custom widget with a clippath and i want to use it as an appbar. I would also add icons to the clippath.

The page will have a singleviewscrollchild.

Any advice on how to make a widget stick to the top while also having a scroll view? The custom appbar should not be scrolled

Comment: What did you tried? Can you share code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found a solution to it. 
Just make the Scaffold return a column. Then add your custom widget as a child.
Then add an Expanded widget as a child after it. In the expanded widget you can add the SingleChildScrollView as a child.

```
 return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xfffafafa),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      CustomAppbar(),
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
              Text("data", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 100),),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Stack` and `Positioned` widget. For example :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          child: CustomAppBar(),
        ),
        ScrollViewWidget(...)
      ],
    );
  }
```